# Solr test framework Runtime Exception: Resource was found on classpath, but cannot be resolved to a normal file

Tags: java, solr, junit, lucene

I've developed a Solr plugin and tested it using [Solr's Test Framework](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_2/solr-test-framework/index.html). I'm trying to upgrade my plugin from Solr 4.6 to Solr 4.10 by replacing the old Solr 4.6 jars with the newer 4.10 jars that my plugin depends upon. The upgrade caused my tests to fail with the following `RuntimeException`:

> Resource was found on classpath, but cannot be resolved to a normal file (maybe it is part of a JAR file): solr/collection1

The resource `solr/collection1` is a directory located on the file system that contains, among other things, the `conf/solrconfig.xml` and `conf/schema.xml` configuration files which the test framework requires.

I have taken a look at the source code of Solr, namely at  [SolrTestCaseJ4.java](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/20f9303f5e2378e2238a5381291414881ddb8172/solr/test-framework/src/java/org/apache/solr/SolrTestCaseJ4.java), where the error originates, and that file contains the following `getFile` method:

```
public static File getFile(String name) {
  final URL url = 
     Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(name);
  try {
    return new File(url.toURI());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Resource was found on classpath, but cannot be resolved to a normal file (maybe it is part of a JAR file): " + name);
  }
  ...
}
```

The `getFile` method receives a string `name="solr/collection1"` as a parameter and then it actually corrupts it by setting the `URL url` local variable to the following illegal path:

> jar:file:/C:/solr-4.10.3/solr-4.10.3/dist/solr-uima-4.10.3.jar!/solr/collection1

Then, the call to the constructor of `File` with `url.toURI()` as a parameter (`new File(url.toURI())`) causes the throwing of an Illegal Argument Exception saying the URI is not hierarchical. This is what's leading to the throwing of the above Runtime Exception.

The first line of the `getFile` method, the one setting the `URL url` local variable, did not exist in Solr 4.6. In Solr 4.6 the `getFile` method initialized the new `File` with the given `name="solr/collection1"` parameter:

```
File file = new File(name); //name = "solr/collection1"
```

This is the reason why that error did not exist in Solr 4.6. Why does the test framework in Solr 4.10 generate that odd `URL`? How can I force it to set the `URL` properly so it can execute my tests without encountering that Runtime Exception?

Comment: Would you create a boiled down test that reproduces the error and post it here or on github?